# What is the origin of the phrase - "the world over"?

Tags: phrase-origin

The phrase "the world over" was used in an article from The Economist. I'm curious to know its origin.

Comment: Since *over* is an adverb that has been used since Old English *ofer* to mean (among other things)  "across an entire region," it is unlikely that "the world over" is unique enough to pinpoint its origin.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the preposition "over" can sometime occur *after* its object in a pseudo-adverbial sense. According to the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/134248)*:

> In the above senses [In or on all or many parts of; everywhere (or here and there) on the surface of; throughout.] often placed after its object, esp. when this is modified by all or the like (cf. through *prep.* 4b). Frequently in **the world over**.
>
> > For the corresponding use in reference to time, as in ‘all the year over’, in which over may be explained adverbially, see sense A. 19b. Even in the present sense, in phrases such as ‘all the world over’, it is difficult to separate the preposition from the adverb when the associated verb admits of both transitive and intransitive construction: cf. ‘you may search London over (= London from end to end) before you find another like it’.

It's been used since at least Middle English:

> *Wars Alexander* (Ashm.) 18 (*MED*)   Alexsandire..aȝte euyn as his awyn all the werd ouire.

*Note: non-academic networks might not have access to this link.

Comment: The full text for the Middle English quote can be found [here](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/APA1967.0001.001/1:2?rgn=div1;view=fulltext).

Answer (score 0):

Sir Walter Raleigh, [1614](https://books.google.com/books?id=JcZMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22the+world+over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0vqfVjIriAhVOnJ4KHRglBtoQ6AEIPzAF):

> And though the City of Dodona was not then built,or (perchance) not so
>   ancient as Dedanim himselfe, yet his Posterity might give it that name
>   in the memory of their first 23 Parent, as it hapned **all the World
>   over**.

I find a couple of uses that might be earlier, but I suspect they are more modern commentary.