# Please explain this sentence: "Organizations the world over need your help!"

Tags: word-usage

This sentence is from bugcrowd.

> Organizations the world over need your help!

To me, it's such a weird usage of English language but grammarly doesn't find anything wrong with it. Yet, I don't understand it. At the very least, I feel that it's missing one or two commas, but that doesn't mean I'm right. However, if it were like this: "Organizations over the world need your help!", then I'd understand it.

If possible please also give two other examples after explaining its construction and meaning.

For context, I include this screenshot:
[image: the sentence in question, in context]

Comment: ***The world over*** is an idiomatic expression meaning “all over the world”. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-world-over - ***see also*** https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497625/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-the-world-over