# What is the function of "the world over"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, literature

> A few weeks before I had been an unknown school-teacher in Dayton, a little town in the mountains of Tennessee. Now I was involved in a trial reported the world over.  (*The Trial That Rocked the World* by John Scopes)

Here's my question that I'm confused about the use of "reported the world over" in the latter sentence. I can roughly guess the meaning maybe is "the world knows the case", however, I don't what grammatical rule it conforms or what kind of collocation it is, especially when the "over" is placed like this.

Comment: "A trial which was reported all over the world."

Comment: I see！ Thank you for your answer！

Comment: The syntax works like this: "reported the world over" is a past-participial clause modifying "trial". The NP "the world over" is an adjunct of place in clause structure (i.e. a modifier in the VP). "Over" is an intransitive preposition as complement of "world".

Comment: I've seen analyses that would class 'over' here as a postposition, just as 'the whole night through' is a variant of 'through the whole night'.

Comment: Postpositions are generally modifiers, but "over" is a complement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-world-over) explains

> If you say that something happens or exists ***the world over***, you mean that it happens or exists *in every part of the world*.
>
> - Some problems are the same ***the world over*** (1).
> - Governments ***the world over*** should do something about it (2).

As you can see in the examples, it can function as an ***adverbial of place*** (as in 1) or it can ***modify a noun*** (as in 2).

In your sentence

> Now I was involved in a trial *reported **the world over***.

*the world over* is an adverbial phrase of place modifying the verb *reported*. (Reported where? Everywhere in the world)

There is another EL&U question, *[What is the origin of the phrase - "the world over"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497625/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-the-world-over)*, where you can find out about the origin of this idiom.

Comment: I got it！ Thank you very much！(*^_^*)

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP to mention that "over" is an intransitive preposition functioning as complement of "world".

Comment: @BillJ: I'm not convinced of that. "The world over" is adverbial, whereas "the world" alone is not; and you can't use other similar intransitive prepositions in this way (e.g. \*"reported the world throughout"). So I think that "the world over" is actually a preposition phrase, with "over" being a *transitive* preposition and "the world" being its complement. (It's exceptional in English for prepositions to follow their complements, but it does happen: *CGEL* chapter 7 § 4.2 mentions *notwithstanding*, *apart*, *aside*, *ago*, and *on*.)

Comment: @ruakh Yes, those are the preps that follow their complement. But "over" is one of a number of preps mentioned on p613 of GCEL, which talks of it being very commonly found without a complement. On that analysis,"the world over" is an NP headed by "world" with the prep "over" as (intransitive) complement of the head.  I agree that the NP is an adjunct (your adverbial) in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ: I'm well aware that "over" *often* appears without a complement (I thought I already made that clear?), but that doesn't mean that that's the best analysis of the specific phrase "the world over".

Comment: @ruakh You said earlier that "over" has "the world" as its complement, i.e. that is not an example of a preposition appearing "without a complement", but of a preposition following its complement. I don't see any compelling reasons to consider "the world over" a PP rather than an NP with "world" as head". Note that CGEL does not claim otherwise.